# Cool applications of reaction diffusion equations

Tags: soft-question, biology

I was thinking my undergrad thesis could be about reaction diffusion equations and their application to biology. For example, I know about pattern formation on the coat of animals, but I was told the modelling there is a bit complicated and maybe excessively tedious for a thesis. Do you know any striking and feasible application of reaction diffusion equations? If you know some other example which you think might be appropriate, it doesn't have to be biology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Diffusion of Drugs in body streams (like using Fick's law) or on infection spreading models based on population density and any other factors you want to tag in and on prey/predator models. Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you happen to know where I could look up some not too complicated models?

Comment: Check this text book Mathematical Biology- J.D. Murray. It got some good models on various biological concepts. It may probably help.

Answer (score 3):

Three possible topics:

- Heat diffusion (stellar models,...)
- Population models, where the population is spatially distributed
- Diffusion of pollutants

Comment: Thank you. Do you have a reference for the first topic?